# How do I let a variable reference a global variable while keeping the value of the global variable unchanged?

Tags: python

So I have this code here:

```
from random import randint

name = input("u");

def ou():
     global allo
     randomlist = "1", "2", "3", "4"

     array = list(randomlist);
     allo = array



allo = ou();


def wagon():
     som = allo
     
     for x in range (0, 4):
          som[x] = "1"


if name == "u":
     wagon();
     print(som)
     print(allo)
```

the output of som and allo are (the last line) ['1', '1', '1', '1']. What should I do to let som reference the value of allo while allowing allo to preserve its original value(1, 2, 3, 4) so sum prints out ['1', '1', '1', '1'] and allo prints out ['1', '2', '3', '4'] at the end? Plus, I need to keep allo as global.

Comment: Try `som = allo[:]` but there are better ways to implement this.

Comment: use global allo before som = allo

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy this might help

Comment: Study list.copy() and do at least an hour of learning on scopes.

Comment: God, I didn't know about list.copy()! Thank you for telling me this. I was trying for a solid day to learn on scopes but It didn't go as well as I've expected... Y'all are angels.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code with minimal changes that will allow it to do what you want it to do.  In addition to the two suggestions noted in the comments, I had to change the call to `au()` to not set `allo`, since the `au()` function doesn't return anything.

```
from random import randint

name = input("u")

def ou():
    global allo
    randomlist = "1", "2", "3", "4"
    array = list(randomlist)
    allo = array

ou()

def wagon():
    global som
    som = allo[:]
    for x in range(0, 4):
        som[x] = "1"

if name == "u":
    wagon()
    print(som)
    print(allo)
```

Here's another version that does things the way I'd suggest you do them while keeping `allo` global and using `allo` to initialize `som`, even though you turn around and redefined `som` completely.  If `allo` was longer than 4 entries, then you'd get a different result if you didn't start with a copy of `allo`, so I left that in.

```
name = input("u")

def ou():
    return ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

allo = ou()

def wagon(allo):
    som = allo[:]
    for x in range(0, 4):
        som[x] = "1"
    return som

if name == "u":
    som = wagon(allo)
    print(som)
    print(allo)
```

Note here that except for keeping your one constraint of ending up with a global `allo`, I got rid of all uses of globals that rely on them being global inside functions, and rather pass values in and out of the functions so that they do not rely on if the variables being used are global.  This is a much better way to go, and is what is generally done.  Relying on functions to change global variables is harder to read and prone to errors.

NOTE: I see the comments about `list.copy`.  You could use `som = list.copy(allo)` instead of `som = allo[:]`.  I always use the former "slice" notation.  I can't think of an advantage to the latter approach, but maybe there is one for larger lists.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I've learned a lot from your feedback. The second example looks way finer.